# Eliminar checkbox de una clase especifica

Tags: html, css

Estoy trabajando con unos checkbox en mi datatable, pero quisiera saber si hay una forma de deshabilitar los checkbox por medio de una clase especifica.

```
<td class="select-checkbox rowcarros"></td
```

Llevo esto al momento

```
td.select-checkbox.rowcarros::before{ display: none !important; } 
td.select-checkbox.rowcarros::after{ display: none !important; }
```

Comment: Si se puede, nos muestras lo que llevas al momento por favor¿?

Comment: intente ocultarlos mediante css, pero no me funciono aun se pueden seleccionar.

Comment: Agrega por favr lo que lleves al momento

Comment: td.select-checkbox.rowcarros::before{
  display: none !important;
   }
   td.select-checkbox.rowcarros::after{
  display: none !important;
   }

Answer (score 0):

Basándonos en la [doc. de Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Podemos hacer lo siguiente:

Declara tu `checkbox` en tu HTML así:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="demo">
```

Y en tu CSS le indicas que el *evento pointer* tenga un valor de `none` con lo cual el elemento queda deshabilitado y el click sobre el no surtirá efecto

```
.demo {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```